# Strange error when installing gazebo

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using groovy, and I followed this tutorial in order to install gazebo http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages
So I when I made `rosdep check --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy`
it said

```
RuntimeError: Multiple packages found with the same name "beginner_tutorials":
- install/share/beginner_tutorials
- src/beginner_tutorials
Multiple packages found with the same name "coverage":
- install/share/coverage
- src/stc
Multiple packages found with the same name "differential_drive":
- install/share/differential_drive
- src/differential_drive
Multiple packages found with the same name "learning_actionlib":
- install/share/learning_actionlib
- src/learning_actionlib
Multiple packages found with the same name "map_server":
- install/share/map_server
- src/coverage/map_server
Multiple packages found with the same name "mark1":
- install/share/mark1
- src/mark1
Multiple packages found with the same name "mark2":
- install/share/mark2
- src/mark2
Multiple packages found with the same name "robot_setup_tf":
- install/share/robot_setup_tf
- src/robot_setup_tf
Multiple packages found with the same name "rosserial":
- install/share/rosserial
- src/rosserial/rosserial
Multiple packages found with the same name "rosserial_arduino":
- install/share/rosserial_arduino
- src/rosserial/rosserial_arduino
Multiple packages found with the same name "rosserial_client":
- install/share/rosserial_client
- src/rosserial/rosserial_client
Multiple packages found with the same name "rosserial_embeddedlinux":
- install/share/rosserial_embeddedlinux
- src/rosserial/rosserial_embeddedlinux
Multiple packages found with the same name "rosserial_msgs":
- install/share/rosserial_msgs
- src/rosserial/rosserial_msgs
Multiple packages found with the same name "rosserial_python":
- install/share/rosserial_python
- src/rosserial/rosserial_python
Multiple packages found with the same name "rosserial_server":
- install/share/rosserial_server
- src/rosserial/rosserial_server
Multiple packages found with the same name "rosserial_xbee":
- install/share/rosserial_xbee
- src/rosserial/rosserial_xbee
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187654/strange-error-when-installing-gazebo/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try

```
rosdep check --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy
```

or executing the command you have stated in the `src` directory, not workspace root.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-24**:
Thank you!! It works fine